# Matt Cap Shading texture

Tags: texturing, shaders

Is there a way which a matt cap can be rendered? I really like this shinny white texture. I tried to simulate it with the basic nodes, but doesn't quite match. Also when I try to render it's loosing it's glossiness which is more visible in the view port shader.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: The material will be for an object. This question of course is for educational purposes which I'm asking. And I'm more interested in rendering it from orthographic view. I know from an angle it has more reflections. But I'd like to know how to maintain gloss/reflections if rendered from orthographic view.

Comment: Thanks for your replies Christopher, can you please take a screenshot of the node set up?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Render Settings and switch the render engine to **Workbench**. This is the render engine the viewport uses and is responsible for matcap lighting.

Then select the **Matcap** you want to use just like you would do from the viewport by using the **Lighting** dropdown below the Sampling menu. Once you press render, each frame will be created using the lighting type that you have specified. It also renders lighting fast because Workbench is designed to provide instantaneous shading for the viewport.

No fancy node editor work required, just switch the render engine, choose a matcap, and that's about it.

[image]

Comment: What an awesome tip, thanks heaps Eric!

Cheers!